# How to set Custom Dimension in Google Analytics using Angulartics

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics, angulartics

I am using [Angulartics](https://luisfarzati.github.io/angulartics/) for track some information to Google Analytics from AngularJS.

I need to set a Custom Dimension, I need to do something like this but using Angulartics third party.

```
ga('set', 'dimension5', 'custom data');
```

In the [documentation](https://luisfarzati.github.io/angulartics/) of Angulartics I just saw `pageTrack()` or `eventTrack()` methods. So I don't if it's possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angulartics allows to set Custom Dimensions and Custom Metrics via `setUserProperties({'dimension' + index : 'dimension-value'})`. For Metrics you pass an object with the analogous data. **The important thing** is to use the **prefix** 'dimension' or 'metric' **concatenated with the index** of your custom dimension/metric. Indices for free users are [0,19], for premium users [0,199].

**Valid examples of setting custom dimensions/metrics are:**

`$analytics.setUserProperties({'dimension1': 'dimension1-value'});`

`$analytics.setUserProperties({'dimension2': 'dimension2-value'});`

`$analytics.setUserProperties({'dimension3': 'dimension3-value'});` ...

`$analytics.setUserProperties({'metric1': 'metric1-value'});`

`$analytics.setUserProperties({'metric2': 'metric2-value'});`

`$analytics.setUserProperties({'metric3': 'metric3-value'});`...

A look into angulartics-google-analytics' source code shows:

```
$analyticsProvider.registerSetUserProperties(function (properties) {
  // add custom dimensions and metrics
  setDimensionsAndMetrics(properties);
});

function setDimensionsAndMetrics(properties) {
    if (window.ga) {
      // add custom dimensions and metrics
      for(var idx = 1; idx<=200;idx++) {
        if (properties['dimension' +idx.toString()]) {
          ga('set', 'dimension' +idx.toString(), properties['dimension' +idx.toString()]);
        }
        if (properties['metric' +idx.toString()]) {
          ga('set', 'metric' +idx.toString(), properties['metric' +idx.toString()]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

See [Allow setting dimensions/metrics via setUserProperties()](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics-google-analytics/pull/9)

Comment: This is more like a comment than an answer to me

Comment: Well I can't comment until I earned 50 reputation :/
(except, I can comment on my own posts)

Comment: @Matyas: I made a fully fletched answer out of my 'comment' :D

Answer (score 1):

As of version `0.1.2` `angulartics.google.analytics` supports setting custom dimensions for both page and event tracking.

You can set custom dimensions like this

```
$analytics.setUserProperties({dimension1: 'myValue'});
```